# How to prove $\forall x\in[0,\pi/2]: \sin{x}+\cos{x} \ge 1?$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Let $x_0\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Then $\sin{x_0}\ge 0$ and $\cos{x_0}\ge 0$

Then $2\sin{x_0}\cos{x_0}\ge 0$ and $\sin{x_0}+\cos{x_0}\ge 0$

Also $(\sin{x_0})^2+(\cos{x_0})^2=1$

Then $(\sin{x_0})^2+(\cos{x_0})^2+2\sin{x_0}\cos{x_0}\ge1$

Then $(\sin{x_0}+\cos{x_0})^2\ge1$

Then $(\sin{x_0}+\cos{x_0})\ge1$

Then $(\sin{x}+\cos{x})\ge1$

Therefore $\forall x\in[0,\pi/2]: \sin{x}+\cos{x} \ge 1.$

I am not sure if it misses anything. Could someone check?

Comment: It seems fine: good job.

Comment: It is correct. But, why do you use two variables $x$ and $x_0$?

Answer (score 5):

Your work is correct.

Here is another way to do it: for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$,

$0 \le \cos x \le 1 \implies \cos^2 x \le \cos x$

$0 \le \sin x \le 1 \implies \sin^2 x \le \sin x$.

So, $\cos x + \sin x \ge \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Still another way:
$$
\sin x +\cos x=\sqrt2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin x+\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos\right)=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}4\right)\ge1
$$
for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, with equality if and only if $x=0$ or $x=\pi/2$.